# Throwing error from grammar to java in antlr3

Tags: java, antlr3, throw

How can I throw the custom error message from the grammar file to the java class(where the parsing and lexing are defined)?

<----------Parser Grammar----------->

```
parser grammar EParser;

@members {

public void displayRecognitionError(String[] tokenNames, RecognitionException e) {
        String hdr = getErrorHeader(e);
        String msg = getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
        System.out.println("hdr and msg...."+hdr+">>>>>>"+msg);
        throw new RuntimeException(hdr + ":" + msg);
    }
}

prog
    : stat+ 
    ;

stat
    : expr SEMI
      | ID EQU expr SEMI
    ;

expr
    : multExpr ((PRM) multExpr)*
    ;

multExpr
    : atom (MUL atom)*
    ;   

atom
    :INT| OPEN expr CLS
    ;
```

<-------------------Java code--------------->

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class TestE {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
ELexer lexer = new ELexer(new ANTLRStringStream("a=9+8;"));
EParser parser = new EParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
try
{
parser.prog();
System.out.println("Parsing successfully...");
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Other exception : " + e.toString());
}    
}
}
```

<------------------Lexer grammar-------------->

```
lexer grammar ELexer;
tokens
{
    ID;
    INT;
    WS;
    EQU;
    PRM;
    OPEN;
    CLS;
    SEMI;
    MUL;
}
@members {
Stack<String> paraphrase = new Stack<String>();
}
ID :('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
INT : '0'..'9'+ ;
EQU:'=';
PRM:'+'|'-';
OPEN:'(';
SEMI:';';
CLS :')';
MUL:'*';
WS : (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();} ;
```

Here my input is `a=9+8`.

When I miss `8` it must give the error message as "Expecting an integer", and when I miss `;` it must say "Missing semicolon".

Like this I have to produce the error message (I don't want the default error message that was produced by the antlr, I need my own error msgs).

How can I achieve this? Whether I have to write the error messages in the grammar file? Or the java code?

Comment: Voting for reoping as it is a valid (and interesting) question with 2 answers already (which shows it's clear enough what's being asked).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to throw custom errors in your grammar. Instead you install your custom error handler and handle exceptions in there. I have written a [fairly complete error handling](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/parsers/mysql-parser.cpp#L247) (however, for the ANTLR3 C target). It might give you some hints what you can use to construct your own error messages.

Comment: I downvoted for the link does no more resolve and it's unclear (at least for me) what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For Java target, you might want to override one or more of these methods:

- `org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.getErrorHeader()`

  - creates error header (where in the input the error occurred)
- `org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.getErrorMessage()`

  - creates the error message itself (what happened)
- `org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.emitErrorMessage()`

  - displays the error (by default on error output / console)
- `org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.displayRecognitionError()`

  - glues it all together:

    ```
    public void displayRecognitionError(String[] tokenNames,
                                        RecognitionException e)
    {
        String hdr = getErrorHeader(e);
        String msg = getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
        emitErrorMessage(hdr+" "+msg);
    }
    ```

You can override them in `@members` section of the grammar as you already did with `displayRecognitionError()`, or if it's longer code it's more convenient to subclass the `org.antlr.runtime.Parser` and put `superClass = MyParser;` in the grammar's `options` section (note that to do it this way for lexer errors as well, you'll have to create a subclass of `org.antlr.runtime.Lexer` as well for the lexer to use).